# What is the difference between EventEmitter<Example> and EventEmitter<Example>()

Tags: angular, angular-event-emitter

What is the difference, if any, between:

`@Output() exampleChange: EventEmitter<Example> = new EventEmitter();`

and

`@Output() exampleChange = new EventEmitter<Example>();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No difference, is practically the same.

**This defines the type and then initializes it:**

```
@Output() exampleChange: EventEmitter<Example> = new EventEmitter();
```

**This is initialized directly:**

```
@Output() exampleChange = new EventEmitter<Example>();
```

***I recommend using the second way***

Answer (score 0):

think about it when you set a variable in a component

```
export class MyTestComponent {
  myNumber:number = 10;
}
-------------------------------------
export class MyTestComponent {
  myNumber = 10;
}
```

In both examples, I created a variable that calls myNumber and set his value to 10,
but in the second one, I gave it a type.
in JS there is no difference between the code except the good order of the script